# Dimension of two complete intersections

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a variety over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $n$. Suppose $V,W$ are closed subvarieties of $A$ with dimensions $d,l$ respectively. Let $Z = V \cap W$ be a complete intersection of $V,W$. If $V' \subset V$ is a closed subvariety of dimension at most $d-2$, is it possible that $(V-V') \cap W = \emptyset $?

I guess if $W$ is a hypersurface, then this should not happen because the dimension should only drop one by complete intersection, but don't know how to show the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is possible for $Z$ to have dimension $\leq d - 2$ and in that case $V' = Z$ has the property that $(V \setminus V') \cap W = \emptyset$.

Comment: I see you point, thank you.

Comment: I'm okay with this answer being deleted, since I don't think the question you asked is quite the one you meant.  However, it won't let me delete it because it has been accepted.  Feel free to "unaccept" my answer if that is possible.  I should have given my answer as a comment.